# overriding \section{} and stripping decorations out of LaTeX source string

Tags: sectioning, pdf

I am trying to solve a problem that I have with Pandoc's LaTeX output ([[1]](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/pull/1148); I have implemented a patch to Pandoc itself but I am also looking for a LaTeX only solution, in case the patch is not acceptable for Pandoc). Basically, I want the strings produced into TOC in rendered PDF document to be nice and not to contain artefacts caused by formatting used for the string in the document text itself:

[image: PIC]

The `!` is a remnant of `\subsection{\lstinline!--enable-debugging!}`.

I am looking for a way to override `\subsection{}` (and other `\chapter` and `\section` commands) to have the effect of `\subsection{\texorpdfstring{\lstinline!--enable-debugging!}{--enable-debugging}`. Is this possible?

Second, is there a way to get from `\lstinline!--enable-debugging!` to `--enable-debugging` using just LaTeX? IOW, is there some command that evaluates into the undecorated version of the text (possibly keeping some basic stuff like `\/` and `{}` in)?

Answer (score 2):

Each sectioning command has an optional argument which, if specified, dictates alternative text that will be placed into the Table of Contents for that section. (See section 2.2 "Sectioning commands" of [*The LaTeX Companion*](https://play.google.com/store/books/details/Frank_Mittelbach_The_LaTeX_Companion?id=iX9MAQAAQBAJ).)

For example, `\section[toc-entry]{title}`.

Just put the alternative text you'd prefer to see in the TOC into the optional argument.

That said, and you didn't provide a MWE to further guide me, I'm not seeing the exclamation mark in the TOC when I use the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\subsection{\lstinline!--enable-debugging!}
\subsection[Alternative section heading for TOC]{\lstinline!--enable-debugging!}
\end{document}
```

[image]